# No builds in TestFlight, yet I still cannot transfer the app because of TestFlight. Thoughts?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to transfer an app. However, despite removing all builds and testers from TestFlight, when trying to transfer, I still get the message:

> TestFlight Beta Testing:
>   You must remove all builds and testers from the app you want transferred and clear each information field below Test Information.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Click on "test information"; what do you see?

Comment: It is blank. I have English (UK) as primary language and the 'Test Information
Beta App Description' text box is blank (not even a single white space).

Comment: Your solution is not professional, it seems like it worked luck by chance :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Make sure all the test flight info has been cleared (description, only one language)
2. Make sure there are no TestFlight testers associated with the app (I removed all users other than the entity's admin user)
3. Create a new build
4. Expire it
5. Leave it for 48 hours
6. Before you log in, clear the browser's cache, cookies etc. (I used an alternative browser instead)

That's it.

I would highlight that the waiting time (step #5) was critical. I created and expired a build on the Wednesday, still had the issue Wednesday and Thursday, but on Friday morning I was able to transfer the app.

Hope the above helps.